# How to extend Django groups for dynamic user types?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a SaaS project which many companies will use and within the companies there will be employees which will be applied to one of two groups: *Supervisor* or *Non-Supervisor*. This will probably look as such:

```
class EmployeeGroup(Group):
    ....
```

Each company will be able to create their own `EmployeeType` which falls into one of the `EmployeeGroups`. e.g. an `EmployeeType` may be *Food and Beverage Supervisor* which is an `EmployeeGroup`: *Supervisor*:

```
class EmployeeType(models.Model):
    ....
    employee_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        default='Server'
    )
    employee_group = models.ForeignKey(
        EmployeeGroup,
        null=True
    )
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
```

And obviously each `User` will have an `EmployeeType`:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ....

    employee_type = models.ManyToManyField(
        EmployeeType,
        null=True,
    )
```

In this situation, can several companies share `EmployeeGroups` without sharing `EmployeeTypes`? My concern is that if an `EmployeeType`: *Server*  is created at **Company A** then **Company B** will not be able to create an `EmployeeType`: *Server* as well. Or that if they do then information will get crossed. It wuold help to have an understanding of how the database works but I do not. Any links to external resources specific to this situation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since `emplyee_type` is *not* unique, there can be as many `'Server'`s as `EmployeeType` as you want. Even multiple ones for the same `Company`.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify and facilitate your requests to DB you may add one more column in your Company table, and write in it every new `employee_groups` when a new employee is hired:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...
    employee_groups = models.ManyToMany(EmployeeGroup, null=True)


class User(models.Model):
    _job = models.ForegnKey(Company, null=True)
    employee_type = models.ManyToManyField(
        EmployeeType,
        null=True,
    )

    def __setattr__(self, attrname, val):
        if attrname == 'job' and isinstance(val, Company):
            val.employee_groups.add(self.employee_type.employee_group)
            self._job = val
```

Now when you will set to some user a new job, that in company wich hire them will added a new `employee_group`.

After that you can easy get all `employee_groups` in any company you want by simple request:

```
employee = Users.objects.get(some_user_pk)
empoyer = Company.objects.get(some_company_pk)
employee.job = employer

print(empoyer.employee_groups)   # will contain employee_group of new employee
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking the time to add/edit this post! I am currently researching the `__setattr__` method and its applications.

Comment: @DavidAlford ok, hope it helps

Comment: @DavidAlford if Model to refer is writed below, just get model name to quotes, like `... = models.ForegnKey("Company")`

Comment: One last question.. why not name the `_job` attribute `company`?

Comment: @DavidAlford Usually the `_` natation in names of class is just convencion of naming of names similar to reserved words or private attributes in python, but in my example it necessary to avoid recursion when in `__setattr__` `self._jobs` gets new value it call `__setattr__` again but attrname now is another - it '_job'. and `if` statement skip them.

Comment: @DavidAlford of course you can name your attributes like `company` and `_company`, insted `job`&`_job`